# Data from a remote Oracle DB is not retrieved using OracleDataAdapter when there are a lot of records

Tags: c#, oracle11g, vpn

Our client's Oracle DB is remotely located and I connect to it over VPN. I have installed all the softwares used for connecting to the Oracle DB (Oracle Client , .Net Client for Oracle etc) and I can connect/use the DB in other parts of application. so its not an issue.

In this situation I load data into into a DataTable. I use the following function and It loads the data into a DataTable when the query returns 3-4k records. It takes a few seconds but it works.

The function I call for executing an Sql query and retrieving a DataTable is

```
    /// <summary>Returns a DataTable based on input query</summary>
    /// <param name="sqlString">sql to execute</param>
    /// <returns>returns DataTable</returns>
    public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(String sqlString)
    {
        OpenConnection();
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        _oracleCommand.CommandText = sqlString;

        try
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(_oracleCommand))
                dbAdapter.Fill(tbl);                
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw new Exception(sqlString, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }

        return tbl;
    }
```

But when I try to load data into a DataTable that is huge, It kind of stucks. The records to be loaded are around 140k and can be more. The query just wont return anything. I waited for the result for around 15-20 minutes, but nothing shows up. and it does not throw any error as well.

The program just stucks on the following line.

> dbAdapter.Fill(tbl);

Any thoughts why?

Regards,
Aamir